# what formula to use to show/match data with reference to another table?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have 2 tables. about phone plan.

1: columns are, Combo and Price. `Rows are 2,3,4,6,12(combo)  and 28,38,44,66,131(price)`. Just showing how much each plan cost.

2: columns are, how much users pay each month(basically the price from 1st table) and the combo they are using.

Basically looks like this :

[image: snap shot of it]

i want `column H` to show what combo the user is using with ref from `column B`? what formula do i have to use? i searched online and they said use index and match?

there are prices that are not correct, u can ignore if u want. pls help thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Not sure where your result column will start but assume it is from `cell H3` and this is the formula you can try:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(G3,C:C,0)),"")
```

Replace that `""` with the content you want.

Comment: i tried on mine, there were some blanks still. In column G, it says 38, but its blank in H.

Comment: Make sure you are referencing the correct cell or take a screenshot of the formula bar with the cell highlighted (don't forget to show row and column numbers) so I can troubleshoot for you.

Comment: ah ok i got it alr. was referencing the wrong cell. thank u so much!!

Comment: hi sorry, but do u happen to know how to include those blanks? eg. if its between 28-37, '2' will appear. 38-43, '3' will appear and so on..

Comment: Change to `=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(G3,C:C,1)),"")` and that should work.  What I've changed is to turn 0 to 1 so it will find the closest match (1) instead of the exact match (0).